# How to get all numbers 1 from array and save it into DB?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 150 variables from `$qA01_1` up to `$qA30_5`. Variables can have values 0 or 1 or 5, randomly for each session. I would like to select all variables which have value 1 and save into database (table “one”) . The same for value 0 (table “zero“) and 5 (table “five“) . Can you help me with my code, please?  I´m sorry for my English. Hope everything is clear.

Here is my shortened array:

```
<?php
session_start();
// variables from
$qA01_1 = $_SESSION['qA01_1'];     
$qA01_2 = $_SESSION['qA01_2'];
$qA01_3 = $_SESSION['qA01_3'];
$qA01_4 = $_SESSION['qA01_4'];
$qA01_5 = $_SESSION['qA01_5']
// up to
$qA30_1 = $_SESSION['qA30_1'];     
$qA30_2 = $_SESSION['qA30_2'];
$qA30_3 = $_SESSION['qA30_3'];
$qA30_4 = $_SESSION['qA30_4'];
$qA30_5 = $_SESSION['qA30_5'];
?>
```

My shortened code, only for variables `$qA01_1` up to `$qA01_5` (not working):

```
<?php
$connect = @MySQL_Connect('localhost', 'root', ' ', 'db');
$vars = get_defined_vars();
foreach ($vars as $varName => $varValue) {
  if (strpos($varName, 'qA') !== false && $varValue === 1) {
    mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO one ((ifnull(qA01_1, 0) + ifnull(qA01_2, 0) + ifnull(qA01_3, 0) + ifnull(qA01_4, 0) + ifnull(qA01_5, 0) ) VALUES ('" .$varName. "', '" .$varValue. "')");
  }
}  
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You appear to be mixing both `MySQL` and `MySQLi`, so you query won't actually insert anything. Please be aware that `MySQL` is deprecated from PHP 5.5 onwards, so please use MySQLi (or PDO) instead: `mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', ' ', 'db');`.

Comment: Connection changed. New connection is now: $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', ' ', 'db');  But still not work. I think that I have another issue.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is in your mysql query:

```
INSERT INTO one 
    ((ifnull(qA01_1, 0) + ifnull(qA01_2, 0) + ifnull(qA01_3, 0) + ifnull(qA01_4, 0) + ifnull(qA01_5, 0) ) 
VALUES 
    ('" .$varName. "', '" .$varValue. "')
```

The Insert syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO table_name 
    ( field1, field2,...fieldN )
VALUES
    ( value1, value2,...valueN );
```

Then I'd suggest a foreach:

```
$varValue = 1;
$values = [];
foreach([1,2,3,4,5] as $index) { // or use range(1,5)
   if($_SESSION['qA01_'.$index] == 1) {
       $values[] = "('qA01_{$index}')";
   };
}
$query = "INSERT INTO one (varValue) VALUES ". implode(',',$values);  
mysqli_query($connect, $query);
```

Comment: Hello Marteen van Middelaar. I think in your code is small issue. I`m not sure with correct position with the semi-colons.

Comment: I've added the missing semicolons.

Comment: I've played with your proposal but all the time issue. Nothing is in database.  I'm thinking if possible make replace $_SESION  with only $ .